# How to bind to checkbox list sql datasource select with stored procedure

Tags: sqldatasource, checkboxlist

I get this error when I call in code behind file.

> Procedure or function 'GetALLSurveyor_ForTeam_Update' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

My code is

```
sdsSurveyor.SelectParameters.Add("@ID", TeamID)
sdsSurveyor.SelectCommand = "GetALLSurveyor_ForTeam_Update"
sdsSurveyor.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure

chklistsurveyor.DataSourceID = "sdsSurveyor"
chklistsurveyor.DataBind()
```

and in aspx file

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklistsurveyor" CellSpacing="10" CellPadding="10" RepeatLayout="Table"
     CssClass="mycheckbox" TextAlign="Right" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="ID"
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSurveyor" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices%>" runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `sdsSurveyor.SelectCommandType` to `SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure`, too! (not just the `.InsertCommandType` as you already do in your code):

```
sdsSurveyor.SelectParameters.Add("@ID", TeamID)
sdsSurveyor.SelectCommand = "GetALLSurveyor_ForTeam_Update"

// make sure you have this line in there somewhere 
sdsSurveyor.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Comment: after using sdsSurveyor.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure   still same error. :(